# ERROR: RVM Ruby not used, run `rvm use 1.9.1` first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and installed ruby using rvm. I have recently upgraded ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.0.0. When I displays ruby version it shows 2.0.0.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
```

When I try to start the solr server, it says a bundle is missing.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=development rake sunspot:solr:start
Could not find unicode_utils-1.4.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Then when I tried to `bundle install`, I am getting the following error.

```
$ bundle install
ERROR: RVM Ruby not used, run `rvm use 1.9.1` first.
```

Listing the know rubies, I am getting the following MRI rubies.

```
$ rvm list known
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p374]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p448]
[ruby-]2.0.0-p195
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p247]
[ruby-]2.0.0-head
ruby-head
```

As I said before, I recently updated ruby to 2.0.0 and removed all other ones. After that everytime I restart the computer, I need to do `bundle install` or do other pre requisites to start the server. I am sure the bundles are installed, but some rvm ruby version is the reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1 : I tried `rvm use 2.0.0-p247`, following is the output which I got.

```
$ rvm use 2.0.0-p247

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

and still I am getting the same error, when `bundle install`

Comment: @RajarshiDas : I tried, please see edit 1

Comment: sorry ignore my first one it should be `rvm use 2.0.0-p195` as per `rvm list` then start `bundle install`..please let me know

Comment: @RajarshiDas I set the `Run command as login shell` and everything worked fine. Thanks for showing me the way.

Answer (score 7):

For `Ruby 2.0.0`
it should be `rvm use 2.0.0-p195` as per your `rvm list` then start `bundle install`..
also sometimes it is required to run `/bin/bash --login`

Answer (score 3):

I set the `Run command as a login shell` in the terminal preferences and restarted the terminal. Now everything works as expected, solr server got started and also `rails server` worked fine.

Thank you all for helping though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, it turned out that I hadn't installed bundler. After I did that, I didn't get the rvm error.

So make sure you have installed bundler.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as per the question title on Ubuntu 14.04.

This wiki page on Atlassian sorted me out though, & it now works fine:
https://kalamuna.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23134210